# python exception error subprocess file missing - but what file?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

i have a code running on python 2.7.3 (windows) and i try to run it on python 2.7.8(windows) and get the following error:

main        : INFO     ** Starting Main **

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\wamp\www\prenderer\src\main.py", line 82, in <module>
    nuke_process = launch_nuke()
  File "C:\wamp\www\prenderer\src\main.py", line 31, in launch_nuke
    query = subprocess.Popen(r"query process", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "F:\python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "F:\python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 958, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
>>>
```

what is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass `shell=True` argument:

```
query = subprocess.Popen(r"query process", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

or pass the command line argument as a list:

```
query = subprocess.Popen(["query", "process"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Otherwise `query process` is recognized as a program instead of `query`.